# How to write random 8 bit binary strings to a file n times

Tags: string, file, python-3.x, binary

So I have an assignment I am to do in my programming class that asks to create a file, write random 8-bit binary strings to it n number of times, and then closes the file.

I understand all of it, except how to make the random binary strings. I am not exactly sure on how to do that. I've read a couple of other questions on here, but none of them seem to help.

Here is my code:

```
def eightBitStrings(n):
    fileName = "eightBits.txt"
    outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
    counter = 0
    while (counter < n):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, 1)
        outputFile.write(str(randomNumber) + "\n")
        counter = counter + 1
    outputFile.close()
```

As of right now it creates 0's and 1's on each line which is good I got that part down now, but I don't know how I would make each of those numbers into random 8 bit strings.

So my output in the file now is:

```
>>>eightBitStrings(6)

0
1
0
0
1
0
```

Whereas I need it to be:

```
>>>eightBitStrings(3)

10001001
11101100
00101110
```

Also I should mention that because this is an assignment I am bound by constraints. I can only use the random library

Comment: Instead of having a function that does it all, break it out into smaller bits.  Start by creating a function that returns an `n` bit string (You can even create the string by appending each part).

Comment: The only issue with that is my teacher only wants the set number of functions in the py file. So this is 1 of 5 of them and the other ones are different functions I have to write so the creation of the 8 bit string has to be within this function. Perhaps I should of clarified that. Sorry.

Comment: That is a dumb requirement; but it doesn't matter.  You should still *think* like you are writing a function to do that part separately.  If you can write a function that returns this, you can just copy/paste the function contents in place of calling the function.  ...so write the function anyway, get the program working, then just `inline` the function code.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion.